# ssl client server with python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

i am trying to create an ssl connection between a client and server socket.
this is my code:
client:

```
    temp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client = ssl.wrap_socket(temp_socket,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, c 
     =ciphers="AES256-GCM-SHA384")
    #print client.ciphers
    client.connect((server_address, int(port)))
```

server:

```
temp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(temp_socket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, 
ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA256")
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
```

and i get error:
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:661) on the client
and [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:590) 
i think the problem might be the fact i am not giving a key file to sockets but i saw the option doesn't exist with RSA key.
any idea what the error might be?

Answer (score 0):

You are not given a certificate and matching keyfile to the server but the cipher you chose uses RSA authentication and thus needs certificate and key. See arguments `certfile`and `keyfile` in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).